# Linux Create user with specials login options

Tags: linux, ssh, users, login, useradd

Hello i need create some users with special privilegies that will be:

- A user that can only login with ssh, no local, it can do anything in pc search, find, etc  like a normal user but only with ssh.
- other user that can login locally and ssh, but can't open any graphical interface
- other    user that can't load desktop, but can open some gui software, like    firefox, chrome, libre office, and so on

There is a way to do that, Thz

distros could be: ubuntu, centos, etc.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a custom pam solution. Pluggable Authentication Modules are capable of doing things like this with minimal difficulty. The challenge is to manage the users. The two ways to accomplish this depends on where you are keeping your main user database. If you are using LDAP, the ldap modules have options to restrict users based on various criteria. Just give each service different ldap options. If you are keeping users in the passwd file I would recommend something like pam_listfile. each service would get a list of users that are allowed to use it, and the appropriate configuration line, and everyone is happy. (you can also set it up for listed users to be denied. The drawback of doing this (either method) is that your distribution's tools for managing pam configuration will not work, and you must configure pam by hand.

Comment: Thz, i will try, i am reading and looking for some tutorials of it.